# Optimizing Initialization of InfluxManager in Flask Endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, flask, influxdb

Title: How to Optimize InfluxManager Initialization in Flask Endpoint for Improved Performance?

I have a Flask endpoint that looks like this:

```py
@api.route("/api/peripherals/last_data", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def digital_overview():
    cfg = Config()
    influxdb_params = cfg.data["system"]["influxdb"]
    influx_client = InfluxManager(
        address=influxdb_params["influxAddress"], port=influxdb_params["influxPort"]
    )
    #...
```

I query this endpoint continuously from the frontend, and I'm concerned about the performance and efficiency of initializing the InfluxManager class each time the endpoint is called. Is there a better way to optimize this process so that I don't have to create a new InfluxManager instance on every request?

I appreciate any suggestions or best practices for handling this situation to improve the endpoint's efficiency and minimize redundant initialization.

I tried to make this class as a singleton like this:

```py
_instance = None

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls._instance is None:
        cls._instance = super(InfluxManager, cls).__new__(cls)
    return cls._instance
```

It works okay for some time, but after some time, something goes wrong, and it starts to report this error:

```
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'OSS', 'X-Influxdb-Version': 'v2.7.0', 'X-Platform-Error-Code': 'unauthorized', 'Date': 'Thu, 12 Oct 2023 06:35:52 GMT', 'Content-Length': '55'})
HTTP response body: b'{"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}'
```

Thanks in advance!